# PHP JSON Data Issue

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to fetch the Ask price from Bittrex API. I'm unable to get this data. I've tried both of the following and neither is working:

```
function bittrex_mco_btc(){

   $data = json_decode(getResource('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-mco'),'TRUE');
   return $data->result->ask;

}

function bittrex_mco_btc(){

   $data = json_decode(getResource('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-mco'),'TRUE');
   return $data['result']['Ask'];

}
```

I think I need to use 'result' because it's an associative array, but I have no idea what's wrong beyond that.

Oh, also here's the getResource:

```
function getResource($url){
$ch = curl_init();
// SETTING CURL OPTIONS
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;}
```

and here's the json:

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"MarketName":"BTC-MCO","High":0.00281740,"Low":0.00162000,"Volume":1490023.83431235,"Last":0.00216002,"BaseVolume":3208.40974458,"TimeStamp":"2017-08-19T04:06:23.39","Bid":0.00216001,"Ask":0.00219186,"OpenBuyOrders":953,"OpenSellOrders":3453,"PrevDay":0.00278935,"Created":"2017-07-02T00:37:16.957"}]}
```

Comment: Just edited it and shared that.

Comment: It should be `json_decode($string, true)`. The second parameter to json_decode is a boolean not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** you should access it like this . because your ask key is inside the `0'th` index .

**2nd:** json_decode second parameter should be a Boolean value .but your given string.

Note: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);`  Understand the structure of array.

**PHP :**

```
     $data = json_decode(getResource('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-mco'),TRUE);

    // $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-mco'),TRUE);

     return $data['result'][0]['Ask'];

    }


?>
```

Comment: Ah, the [0]! Can you please explain why I need the 0?

Comment: echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data); . because your ask key is inside the o'th index .

Comment: Thank you so much by the way! It worked. But I'd love an explanation for why I needed that 0 in between result and ask. I thought in an associative array, I'd just need result before.

Answer (score 0):

`getResource` is not a native php function is it from a library?

Comment: I wrote it. I shared it. I have it in other functions getting from other resources and it seems to be working for them but not for Bittrex.